# MYSQL error syntax near LIMIT 0, 25

Tags: mysql

I have a query with this structure trying to run in PHPMYADMIN. I going crazy with this, somebody can tell me what is wrong in here?

If i run the SELECTs separately, they work just fine. When i run togheter with the union it crash.

```
SELECT 1 AS orden, CONCAT(profesor.nombre,' ', profesor.apellido) profesor, cobro.monto 
FROM cobro INNER JOIN profesor ON cobro.idProfesor = profesor.idProfesor WHERE cobro.idEstado=9
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS orden, CONCAT(profesor.nombre,' ', profesor.apellido) profesor, retiro.monto 
FROM retiro INNER JOIN profesor ON cobro.idProfesor = profesor.idProfesor WHERE retiro.idEstado=11
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS orden, 'TOTAL' profesor, SUM(monto) AS monto 
FROM (SELECT monto FROM cobro UNION ALL SELECT monto FROM retiro) AS T1
```

MYSQL Error = #1064 - Syntax error near 'LIMIT 0, 25'

Comment: I don't see any `LIMIT` in the question!

Comment: Thats why i don't understand neither. But im runing this in phpmyadmin

Comment: Maybe you're not running the query you think, or possibly something got cached and is running?

Comment: Yes! What Tim wrote make a lot of sense, and I don't believe you actually run _SELECT **field** FROM **something**_ (But perhaps i'm wrong) so if you can, post here the real query and add more context, because it's currently a type of a guessing game

Comment: I tried run this query without the derived table and works fine. Its in the derived table line that give the problem and phpmyadmin mark me up as a syntax error.

Comment: Running it in PhpMyAdmin is the key. If you run it from the actual MySQL command line, you'll probably find that it works. That's a big clue which will enable you to investigate further, and tailor your question if you are still stuck.

Comment: You are right!!! @BoundaryImposition Thank you all for answer me guys

Comment: Please don't vandalise your own question. If it's solved, either post the answer or remove the question altogether.

Comment: @DavidTorres Please consider [self-answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question for future users with similar issue. Describe what was the issue you're having and what you did to solve it

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Oh, It look like they need 15+ rep. for that

Comment: Ok. I will do that @ÁlvaroGonzález. And im sorry, newbie things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query was right. The problem was Phpmyadmin that give that error when you have a query with union and a derived table like this.

```
SELECT field FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT field FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS table2
```

If you run in the console, you will find no problems.